# Configurable product super attribute Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: configurable-product, price, error, sql, superattribute

I have a script that creates the new configurable product, but I get an error when I try to save the super attribute price configuration, here's my code:

```
function createConf(){
//other code before...

$configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
//Load the 3 simple products already created
$idIT = 5;
$idEU = 6;
$idRW = 7;
$_productSIT = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idIT);
$_productSEU = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idEU);
$_productSRW = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idRW);
$configProduct
    ->setWebsiteIds(1)
    ->setAttributeSetId(4)
    ->setTypeId('configurable')
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
    ->setSku($skuNew)//I have defined this variable before and it's value it's taken from an external database
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setTaxClassId(4)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setPrice($_productSIT->getPrice())
    ->setDescription('descr')
    ->setShortDescription('short descr')
    ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
            'manage_stock' => 1,
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
        )
    );

 // [...] after that I set all the other attributes like name and so on...

$listinoId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')
    ->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'listino');

$configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($listinoId));
$configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
$configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

$configurableProductsData = array();
$configurableProductsData[$idIT] = array(
    '0' => array(
        'label' => $_productSIT->getAttributeText('listino'),
        'attribute_id' => $listinoId,
        'value_index' => $_productSIT->getListino(),
        'is_percent' => '0',
        'pricing_value' => '0'
    )
);
$configurableProductsData[$idEU] = array(
    '0' => array(
        'label' => $_productSEU->getAttributeText('listino'),
        'attribute_id' => $listinoId,
        'value_index' => $_productSEU->getListino(),
        'pricing_value' => '0'
    )
);
$configurableProductsData[$idRW] = array(
    '0' => array(
        'label' => $_productSRW->getAttributeText('listino'),
        'attribute_id' => $listinoId,
        'value_index' => $_productSRW->getListino(),
        'pricing_value' => '0'
    )
);

$configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
$configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
$configProduct->save();

//Now I call the function to update the super attribute price
insertPriceConf($configProduct->getId(), $_productSRW->getPrice(), $_productSIT->getPrice(), $_productSEU->getPrice());}

 function insertPriceConf($id, $prezzoRW, $prezzoBase, $prezzoEU){
 $product = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/Product")->load($id);
$associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray(($product));

foreach ($associatedProducts as $attributeData) {
    $idAt = isset($attributeData['id']) ? $attributeData['id'] : null;
    $size = sizeof($attributeData['values']);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {
        if ($attributeData['values'][$j]['label'] == 'IT') {
            $attributeData['values'][$j]['pricing_value'] = '0';
        }
        if ($attributeData['values'][$j]['label'] == 'RW') {
            $attributeData['values'][$j]['pricing_value'] = $prezzoRW;
        }
        if ($attributeData['values'][$j]['label'] == 'EU') {
            $attributeData['values'][$j]['pricing_value'] = $prezzoEU;
        }

        try {
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')
                ->setData($attributeData)
                ->setId($idAt)
                ->setStoreId(1)
                ->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->save();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

My problem is that I use these functions in a loop because I need to insert new products taken from an external database, when I run the code the first configurable product is created correctly, with the super attribute price and so on, but from the second one to the last, the product is created, and there is also the associated simple product but I cannot set the price of the super attribute, this is the error given:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4606-176' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID', query was: `` UPDATE `catalog_product_super_attribute` SET `product_id` = ?, `attribute_id` = ?, `position` = ? WHERE (product_super_attribute_id='758') ``

Please help me. I tried everything found on the internet but nothing works

Comment: I have answer to a similar question here
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50131/updating-configurable-products-constraint-exception/52180#52180

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Configurable Products Constraint Exception](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50131/updating-configurable-products-constraint-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that a row with the given product_id and attribute_id combination already exists (there is a UNIQUE index over these columns).

I see that you use `$product = Mage::getSingleton("catalog/Product")->load($id);` - not sure if this is the only cause of your problem but it's definitely related.

Never use the product model as a singleton. This way you reuse the same object in each iteration of the loop and it contains cached information which is not reset on `load()`.

Solution: Replace `getSingleton()` with `getModel()`

Comment: reusing the `getModel()` can bring performance improvements. Requires calling the `reset()` method before doing another load.

Comment: The performance improvement is negligible in comparision to the possible bugs you introduce because things are reused that you don't want to be reused.